# Allowing comments on Entityform

Tags: 7, comments, entities

My current project requires the use of comments on submitted data on entityform. I believe this functionality is built in drupal 7 node. By any chance, is it possible to implement it also on Entityform? if not is there a possible workaround to meet my project requirements?

Comment: I wrote Entityforms but if you are having users submit data and then you want other users to comment on the data why are you just using nodes for the submitted data?

Answer (score 0):

Comments in Drupal 7 are tied to Nodes. You could try the [Reply](https://drupal.org/project/reply) module but it is still a dev project.

Usually though in situation like this though if a project needs some functionality that is built into Nodes in Drupal core I think it might be case where Nodes should really be used.